# Custom Layout on UICollectionView using Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

[Desire Layout on CollectionView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pynxX.png)

I having trouble achieving a custom layout on collectionview in swift 3.0. Its been two days searching on similar layout but I couldn't find one. Pls anyone help me to achieve my desire custom layout.

Comment: Is it a horizontal scroll or vertical ?

Comment: horizontal scroll

Comment: you can use delegate method for resize the collection cell.

Comment: yeah but I have problem with the arrangement of the cell

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing and there are many 3rd party lib to help out. But I suspect you don't know how to do layout and spacing among cell.

Here is the best help ..just play with values to get your similar layout.

```
override func prepareLayout() {
 // 1
 if cache.isEmpty {
// 2
let columnWidth = contentWidth / CGFloat(numberOfColumns)
var xOffset = [CGFloat]()
for column in 0 ..< numberOfColumns {
  xOffset.append(CGFloat(column) * columnWidth )
}
var column = 0
var yOffset = [CGFloat](count: numberOfColumns, repeatedValue: 0)

// 3
for item in 0 ..< collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(0) {

  let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: item, inSection: 0)

  // 4
  let width = columnWidth - cellPadding * 2
  let photoHeight = delegate.collectionView(collectionView!, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath: indexPath, 
      withWidth:width)
  let annotationHeight = delegate.collectionView(collectionView!,
      heightForAnnotationAtIndexPath: indexPath, withWidth: width)
  let height = cellPadding +  photoHeight + annotationHeight + cellPadding
  let frame = CGRect(x: xOffset[column], y: yOffset[column], width: columnWidth, height: height)
  let insetFrame = CGRectInset(frame, cellPadding, cellPadding)

  // 5
  let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWithIndexPath: indexPath)
  attributes.frame = insetFrame
  cache.append(attributes)

  // 6
  contentHeight = max(contentHeight, CGRectGetMaxY(frame))
  yOffset[column] = yOffset[column] + height

  column = column >= (numberOfColumns - 1) ? 0 : ++column
}
```

}
}

Reference [UIcollectionView Layout](https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest)